# Changes to redux store not reflected inside child component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a hangman game when all lives are gone it displays a modal saying 'RESTART?'. When you click on it it resets the game and also resets 'letters map' (resets pressed buttons). but even when 'restarted' state is set to true after clicking on the modal, letters map is not reset!

Code is at github:
https://github.com/gunitinug/hangman-clicked-redux/blob/debug/src/actions/actions.js

https://github.com/gunitinug/hangman-clicked-redux/blob/debug/src/reducer/reducer.js

https://github.com/gunitinug/hangman-clicked-redux/blob/debug/src/Game/Game.js

https://github.com/gunitinug/hangman-clicked-redux/blob/debug/src/Letters/Letters.js

I'll go through relevant codes:

Game.js

```js
const Game = props => { 

    // Reset game when game is restarted
    // Not only you reset game you reset letters map too!
    const resetGameHandler = () => {
        // these are dispatch calls to the store
        props.next(1);
        // HOPEFULLY setting restarted state on and off will reset the letters map and then 
        // reset it for next restart event.
        props.restarted(true);
        props.restarted(false);
    };

    let modal = null;
    if (props.state.lives === 0)
    {
        modal = <React.Fragment>
                <div className={styles.overlay}></div>
                <div className={styles.askforrestart + ' ' + styles.shake} onClick={resetGameHandler} >RESTART?</div>
            </React.Fragment>;
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {modal}
            <div>
                ...
                <Letters ... />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Letters.js

```js
const Letters = props => {
    const [lettersMap, setLettersMap]=useState(
        {
            "a":false,"b":false,"c":false,"d":false,"e":false,"f":false,"g":false,"h":false,"i":false,"j":false,"k":false,"l":false,"m":false,"n":false,"o":false,"p":false,"q":false,"r":false,"s":false,"t":false,"u":false,"v":false,"w":false,"x":false,"y":false,"z":false
        }
    );

    // reset letters map only after riddle is just solved and not every time.
    // also reset leters map if game restarts.
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (props.isSolved) {
            setLettersMap(
                {
                    "a":false,"b":false,"c":false,"d":false,"e":false,"f":false,"g":false,"h":false,"i":false,"j":false,"k":false,"l":false,"m":false,"n":false,"o":false,"p":false,"q":false,"r":false,"s":false,"t":false,"u":false,"v":false,"w":false,"x":false,"y":false,"z":false
                }
            );
        }

    // this doesn't work!
    // even when store's restarted state (linked to props.isRestarted) is true, it won't reset the letters map!
        if (props.isRestarted) {
            console.log('resetting letters map...');
            setLettersMap(
                {
                    "a":false,"b":false,"c":false,"d":false,"e":false,"f":false,"g":false,"h":false,"i":false,"j":false,"k":false,"l":false,"m":false,"n":false,"o":false,"p":false,"q":false,"r":false,"s":false,"t":false,"u":false,"v":false,"w":false,"x":false,"y":false,"z":false
                }
            );
        }
    }, [props.isSolved, props.isRestarted]);

    const renderedLetters = ...;

    return (
        <div className={ styles.letters }>{renderedLetters}</div>
    );
}
```

So the issue I must solve is, when store's `restarted` state is set to true by calling `props.restarted(true)` from Game.js, I expect the letters map to be reset from Letters.js, but this is not the case.

It seems changes to `props.isRestarted` (linked to the store's `restarted` state) is not reflected inside Letters.js.

Comment: Are the right actions dispatched and do they change the state correctly (check redux devtools), this information is missing in your question. Where does `props.isRestarted` come from? You refer to code on github that is completely different from the code in your question. Changes in an event handler are batched so you if you want to force a re render when toggling restarted on and off in resetGameHandler you can do: `props.restarted(true);Promise.resolve().then(()=>props.restarted(false))`

Comment: Sorry about that. Click on History and choose the commit "resetting letters map after restart doesn't work". Thx!